# createOrUpdate() always creates a new entry in the database with ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite

In my Android project, ORMLite is functioning as a cache. I'm downloading data from a web server and placing it in the database. I'm calling `createOrUpdate` on my objects, but duplicates are appearing in the database. The database entries are identical except for the primary key (which is simply an auto incremented integer). I think that since my second object doesn't yet have a primary key, ORMLite considers the two as being different, even though every other field is identical.

Does anyone know if this is true?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should not be calling `createOrUpdate` unless your object *already* has an id field set.  The way `ORMLite` determines whether or not it exists in the database is to do a query-by-id on it.  The code does:

```
ID id = extractId(data);
// assume we need to create it if there is no id  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
if (id == null || !idExists(id)) {
    int numRows = create(data);
    return new CreateOrUpdateStatus(true, false, numRows);
} else {
    int numRows = update(data);
    return new CreateOrUpdateStatus(false, true, numRows);
}
```

I'll expand the javadocs to explain this better.  They are *very* weak there.  Sorry.  I've updated them to be:

> This is a convenience method for creating an item in the database if it does not exist. The id is extracted from the data argument and a query-by-id is made on the database. If a row in the database with the same id exists then all of the columns in the database will be updated from the fields in the data parameter. If the id is null (or 0 or some other default value) or doesn't exist in the database then the object will be created in the database. This also means that your data item must have an id field defined.

Comment: Awesome! I was starting to suspect this was the behavior. Thanks for shedding some light.

Comment: Actually I need the behaviour the OP is having +1 for shedding some light on the default value required to get a new insert :) !

Comment: How about a column with the `generatedId = true` Database Field annotation? Also then it always creates a new entry in the database. See [`Bug #173`](http://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/bugs/173/).

Comment: would'nt it be good to take "<Id>" field as argument? As the User might use some other name for primary key .. I'm facing this issue :)

Comment: @Gray i can not underestanding this topic, can you link me for better sample to how to use simply `createOrUpdate` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you manually need to extract the id of the already existing entry and then `update` the database, based on your actual unique identifier. Example with unique URLs:

```
CacheItem newEntry = fetchEntry("..."); // fetch it here
List<CacheItem> existing = mDao.queryForEq("url", newEntry.getUrl());
if (existing.size() > 0) {
    int id = existing.get(0).getId();
    newEntry.setId(id);
    mDao.update(newEntry);
} else mDao.create(newEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

set your primary key for it to work normally.

@DatabaseField(columnName = "id",uniqueIndex = true)
private int id;

Worked for me. Exceptions are thrown at background but it works :D