# Getting "UNIQUE constraint failed" exception using Ormlite createOrUpdate() method

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have several calls throughout my app where tables in my database are updated through calls to `.createOrUpdate()`

The [documentation suggests](http://core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#createOrUpdate(T)) from this calls:

> This is a convenience method for creating an item in the database if it does not
>   exist. The id is extracted from the data parameter and a query-by-id
>   is made on the database. If a row in the database with the same id
>   exists then all of the columns in the database will be updated from
>   the fields in the data parameter. If the id is null (or 0 or some
>   other default value) or doesn't exist in the database then the object
>   will be created in the database. This also means that your data item
>   must have an id field defined.

My understanding is then that, when calling createOrUpdate(), the underlying code should be calling "insert" if the Database doesn't contain the row and "update" if the row exists.

What seems to be happening is that the underlying code is calling "insert" when the row already exists causing the exception.

Does anybody know why this is happening or how to avoid it?

Exception below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object
    Feed(id=126275579_organisations-email_58284484, type=organisations-email, category=1, msg=<p>Body</p>, regarding=Bobby Castle, subject=Subject, createdTs=2016-01-04T09:59:27+00:00, completed=0, read=0, starred=0, archived=0, remoteAttachments=[], localAttachments=null, authorId=250008275, authorName=Live Regression Test, authorImg=null): INSERT INTO `feed` (`id` ,`type` ,`category` ,`msg` ,`regarding` ,`subject` ,`createdTs` ,`completed` ,`read` ,`starred` ,`archived` ,`authorId` ,`authorName` ,`authorImg` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao.createOrUpdate(RuntimeExceptionDao.java:252)
     at uk.co.test.test.data.orm.models.Feed.createOrUpdate(Feed.java:81)
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.server.CategoryInteractor$6.onSuccessfulResponse(CategoryInteractor.java:308)
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.server.CategoryInteractor$6.onSuccessfulResponse(CategoryInteractor.java:290)
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.common.StandardCallbackRunnable.checkStandardResponse(StandardCallbackRunnable.java:27)
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.common.StandardCallbackRunnable.checkStandardResponse(StandardCallbackRunnable.java:12)
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.common.CallbackRunnable.success(CallbackRunnable.java:127)
     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object Feed(id=126275579_organisations-email_58284484, type=organisations-email, category=1, msg=<p>Body</p>, regarding=Bobby Castle, subject=Subject, createdTs=2016-01-04T09:59:27+00:00, completed=0, read=0, starred=0, archived=0, remoteAttachments=[], localAttachments=null, authorId=250008275, authorName=Live Regression Test, authorImg=null): INSERT INTO `feed` (`id` ,`type` ,`category` ,`msg` ,`regarding` ,`subject` ,`createdTs` ,`completed` ,`read` ,`starred` ,`archived` ,`authorId` ,`authorName` ,`authorImg` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
     at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:135)
     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:450)
     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:310)
     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(BaseDaoImpl.java:336)
     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao.createOrUpdate(RuntimeExceptionDao.java:249)
     at uk.co.test.test.data.orm.models.Feed.createOrUpdate(Feed.java:81) 
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.server.CategoryInteractor$6.onSuccessfulResponse(CategoryInteractor.java:308) 
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.server.CategoryInteractor$6.onSuccessfulResponse(CategoryInteractor.java:290) 
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.common.StandardCallbackRunnable.checkStandardResponse(StandardCallbackRunnable.java:27) 
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.common.StandardCallbackRunnable.checkStandardResponse(StandardCallbackRunnable.java:12) 
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.common.CallbackRunnable.success(CallbackRunnable.java:127) 
     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: inserting to database failed: INSERT INTO `feed` (`id` ,`type` ,`category` ,`msg` ,`regarding` ,`subject` ,`createdTs` ,`completed` ,`read` ,`starred` ,`archived` ,`authorId` ,`authorName` ,`authorImg` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
     at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
     at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.insert(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:169)
     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:91)
     at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:450) 
     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:310) 
     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(BaseDaoImpl.java:336) 
     at com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao.createOrUpdate(RuntimeExceptionDao.java:249) 
     at uk.co.test.test.data.orm.models.Feed.createOrUpdate(Feed.java:81) 
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.server.CategoryInteractor$6.onSuccessfulResponse(CategoryInteractor.java:308) 
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.server.CategoryInteractor$6.onSuccessfulResponse(CategoryInteractor.java:290) 
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.common.StandardCallbackRunnable.checkStandardResponse(StandardCallbackRunnable.java:27) 
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.common.StandardCallbackRunnable.checkStandardResponse(StandardCallbackRunnable.java:12) 
     at uk.co.test.test.interactors.common.CallbackRunnable.success(CallbackRunnable.java:127) 
     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: feed.id (code 1555)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
     at android.
```

Comment: Is this reproducible?  Have you tried debugging it to see what's going on?  The ORMLite code is just doing a look for id and if it is null or it doesn't exist, create the item.  https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.java#L362

Comment: It's not reproduceable on demand, but it does happen. I'm wondering if it might be a threading issue where I'm accessing the database between the calls "check if exists" and "insert" statement.

Comment: Hard to know but certainly if two threads were calling checkIfExists for the same object at the same time, you would have problems.

Comment: When I wrote it I assumed that thread safety was being taken care of in the library :/ Reads and writes are obviously thread safe via transactions, this one doesn't seem to be protected in the same way :/

Comment: Uh yeah, no.  ORMLite can be used fine with multiple threads but it doesn't do any synchronization.  That would be heavy weight.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288297/createorupdate-always-creates-a-new-entry-in-the-database-with-ormlite

Comment: Hi @Gray, I am working on a chat app and using ormlite to make a queue for messages that need to send messages (new messages as well as message to report status). I wrote a script to send messages frequently (upto 400ms). Running this script on 2 device to send message to each other upto 30 messages I get this exception for 3 to 4 times.

Comment: See my new answer @AsimHabib.  I would recommend that you make that specific call inside of a `synchronized` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding is then that, when calling createOrUpdate(), the underlying code should be calling "insert" if the Database doesn't contain the row and "update" if the row exists.

This is true however the operation is not (and cannot be) atomic because multiple database calls are being made to accomplish it.  There is no locking that is done in the DAO method – although maybe there should be.

If we look at the [`BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(...)` code](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.java#L380) you can see that it does:

1. Extract the ID from the entity in question.
2. Looks it up in the database to see if it exists.
3. Calls `update(...)` if it exists otherwise `create()`.

Because there are multiple calls to the database going on, then there are race conditions if multiple threads are executing this method at the same time.

> ```
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
> ```

Right, if you are using this DAO method with threads (and `createIfNotExists(...)` which also does 2 database calls) then I would do so within a `synchronized` block:

```
synchronized (dao) {
    status = dao.createOrUpdate(...);
}
```