# Android ORMLite and create if not exists logic

Tags: crud, dao, ormlite

Create if not exist IMHO means that `ORM` will create record in table only if it doesn't exist already.

I thought that ORMLite uses such logic by default. But `DAO`'s `create` method just makes duplicates of records. I have tried `createOrUpdate` and `createIfNotExist` methods, but none of them work, as I wish.

I've found another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288297/createorupdate-always-creates-a-new-entry-in-the-database-with-ormlite), which explains that `createOrUpdate` perform check on ids, which have default (null or 0) values in my `DTO`s.

So do I need to create my own `DAO`s, inherit them from ORMLite's `BaseDaoImpl` class and override `createIfNotExist` method? This is the only idea, which comes to my mind so far. Is there better way to realize desirable logic?

**EDIT**

I've tried to override `createIfNotExist` method of custom `DAO`, but seems like call to it can be performed only directly, that is top-level table doesn't performs call of foreign key's `createIfNotExist`.

Seems like I need to define `CRUD` interface with my own methods and realize them on `BaseDaoImpl` methods.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you may want to use my tiny library, which adds such feature

[DuplicatelessORMLite](https://github.com/MikeHerasimov/DuplicatelessORMLite/tree/master)